# How to activate feature,add master page/site pages etc automatically when we create a site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What are the best ways to activate feature,add master page/site pages etc automatically when we create a site? Apart from feature stapling, do we have any other ways to achieve it

Answer (score 4):

You can use SPWebEventReceiver.WebProvisioned event which fires after a subsite is fully provisioned

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
    base.WebProvisioned(properties);
    SPWeb web = properties.Web;
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    // your code to activate the feature, add master page etc.

    web.Update();
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```